# How to get errno when epoll_wait returns EPOLLERR?

Tags: linux, epoll

Is there a way to find out the `errno` when `epoll_wait` returns `EPOLLERR` for a particular fd?

Is there any further information about the nature of the error?

**Edit:**

Adding more information to prevent ambiguity

`epoll_wait` waits on a number of file descriptors. When you call `epoll_wait` you pass it an array of `epoll_event` structures:

```
struct epoll_event {
           uint32_t     events;    /* Epoll events */
           epoll_data_t data;      /* User data variable */
       };
```

The `epoll_data_t` structure has the same details as the one you used with `epoll_ctl` to add a file descriptor to epoll:

```
typedef union epoll_data {
           void    *ptr;
           int      fd;
           uint32_t u32;
           uint64_t u64;
       } epoll_data_t;
```

What I'm looking for is what happens when there is an error on one of the file descriptors that epoll is waiting on.

ie: `(epoll_event.events & EPOLLERR) == 1` - is there a way to find out more details of the error on the file descriptor?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use getsockopt and SO_ERROR to get the pending error on the socket

```
int       error = 0;
socklen_t errlen = sizeof(error);
if (getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (void *)&error, &errlen) == 0)
{
    printf("error = %s\n", strerror(error));
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the lateness of the reply - this worked perfectly - thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor point: Your test won't work correctly, for two reasons.  If EPOLLERR is defined as, say, 0x8, then your test will be comparing 8 with one (since == has higher precedence than &), giving you a zero, then anding that with the event mask.

What you want is: (epoll_event.events & EPOLLERR) != 0 to test for the EPOLLERR bit being set.

Comment: This should have been a comment not an answer

Answer (score -2):

epoll_wait returns -1 when an error occurs and sets errno appropriately. See "man 2 epoll_wait" for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but as you will see from my comments on the  answer by @HongZhou, this is not what I'm looking for. I am aware that if epoll_wait returns -1 for the epoll file descriptor I can use errno to get the error. What I'm looking for is when epoll_event.events & EPOLLERR == 1 for one of the file descriptors epoll is waiting on

Answer (score -4):

Include errno.h and use perror to see the error message.
Basically error is from the epfd or interupt, it will not arise from the file descriptor in your set.

## include "errno.h"

```
if(epoll_wait() == -1)
    {
      perror("Epoll error : ");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is not what I'm looking for. I am aware that if epoll_wait returns -1 for the epoll file descriptor I can use errno to get the error. What I'm looking for is when epoll_event.events & EPOLLERR == 1 for one of the file descriptors epoll is waiting on

Comment: 1.EBADF - epfd is not a valid file descriptor.
2.EFAULT - The memory area pointed to by events is not accessible with write permissions.
3.EINTR - The call was interrupted by a signal handler before any of the requested events occurred or the timeout expired; see signal(7).
4.EINVAL - epfd is not an epoll file descriptor, or maxevents is less than or equal to zero.
Above are the only 4 errors in the man. Under what circumstances will EPOLLERR == 1?

Comment: For socket, I'm using this flag to check for closed peers though: EPOLLRDHUP.

Comment: I'm not looking for `epoll_wait` errors, I'm looking for information on the errors returned for file descriptors being **watched** by epoll